# Adding OnClientClick to a button generated at runtime

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have created a button at runtime and would to add OnClientClick property of the button,to execute some javascript function, example the alert(), in this case. This piece of code works in firefox and other browsers but not chrome. I would appreciate some help here.

```
    Button addButton = new Button { Text = "test", CssClass = "btn", UseSubmitBehavior = false};
    addButton.OnClientClick = "javascript:alert('button has being clicked');";
```

Comment: Could you show us the generated HTML?

Comment: Does the console in chrome say anything? Maybe there is an unrelated JS error elsewhere that is preventing other JS on the page from executing.

Comment: Remove the `javascript:` is not necessary. Just `addButton.OnClientClick = "alert('button has being clicked');";`

Comment: Thanks, silly me, just realised it was an extension(Better Popup Blocker) that was causing it. Because it was quiet strange as it used to work on chrome earlier, till I installed it. Wow!